# Is there an easy way to find duplicated text in resource files within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, localization

In reviewing a project I am working on, I have stumbled upon several places where the same text string appears in multiple resource (.resx) files.

I would like to review all such duplicates because I believe that in the majority of cases there is no reason for the duplication (i.e. the text in question is used in the same context and should be moved to, or used from, a resource file that is accessible to all places that text needs to be used).

Is there any easy way to identify such duplicates, either directly in Visual Studio or using an add-in like ReSharper?

**Edit:** I should perhaps give an example of one of the situations I've already found and fixed so the problem is a little clearer. I found three instances of the text string "Continue" in the same project. Each instance had a different name (e.g. name="Continue", name="Contnue" [sic] and name="AdvanceToNextPage"). Two instances appeared in the same .resx file, one appeared in a different .resx file, and since they were all within the same project the text could (and arguably should) have been pulled from an entry from the main Properties/Resources.resx file.

Comment: You can use *Ctrl+Shift+F* and list all occurrences of the string you are looking for, however, you have to remove (or edit) it manually then (without help of the resources designer). You can also specify types of files to consider in the search.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. While your comment is accurate it doesn't quite meet the "easy" part of the question. ;-) For starters, I don't (yet) know the entire set of strings that are duplicated.

Comment: Hey, if you know a part of the string to be found, you can use search box (as described in my previous comment) with a regular expression. A little bit more explanation is needed to make it easy, so I'll post it as an answer :).

Comment: Sorry, I think I've misunderstood you, because you've probably meant you want to find duplicates, but don't know some of the duplicated strings at all. Is this right? In this case, I suppose a simple helper application could parse the resx files and give you the answer :).

Comment: That's the whole point Lucas. I don't even know a _part_ of the string (or icon, or whatever the resource may be), because I don't _yet_ know that it's duplicated elsewhere. I'm guessing I'm going to have to create something myself (which won't be hard) to iterate through all resource files in a solution (or at least in a project), and build a look-up.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link for a quick-and-dirty XSLT that will go through a RESX file and print out a list of duplicate resources by ID along with a count of how many were found:

http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2006/04/06/finding-duplicates-in-resx-using-xslt.aspx

Comment: Thanks vinitha. Unfortunately, this doesn't quite answer my question as the XSLT in question only looks at a single resource file, and as stated in my question I'm looking for a way to check for duplication across multiple resource files. The VS Add-in referenced on that page looks worth investigation, but unfortunately the link is dead. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Resx Resource Manager](http://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/) and select 'all' files. Then you can export them to Excel and let Excel find the duplicates.